# Selinium IDE - type random stored variable

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

Using Selenium IDE

I'm trying to type one of 6 stored variables

I store the 6 variables (credit card numbers) as CC1 , CC2 etc.

I also store a random number between 1-6 which Im hoping to use to "randomly select" one of my stored variables

thoughts?

```
<tr>
<td>store</td>
<td>4555555555000001</td>
<td>cc1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>store</td>
<td>4555555555000002</td>
<td>cc2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>store</td>
<td>4555555555000003</td>
<td>cc3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>store</td>
<td>4555555555000004</td>
<td>cc4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>store</td>
<td>4555555555000005</td>
<td>cc5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>store</td>
<td>4555555555000006</td>
<td>cc6</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>storeEval</td>
<td> Math.floor(Math.random()*6) +1</td>
<td>drop1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>echo</td>
<td>${cc${drop1}}</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
```

the echo returns ${cc6} not the variable cc6

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a javascript switch statement.

> ```
> <tr>
>   <td>storeEval</td>
>   <td>switch(Math.floor(Math.random()*6) +1) {case 1: 455001; break; case 2: 455002; break; case 3: 455003; break; case 4: 455004; break; case 5: 455005; break; default: 455006; break; }</td>
>   <td>randomcard</td>
> </tr>
> <tr>
>   <td>echo</td>
>   <td>${randomcard}</td>
>   <td></td>
> </tr>
> ```